# Multiple Values in RealUrl

Tags: typo3, realurl

When I got multiple values in my URL of the same name
e.g `…&tx_myext_pi1[crit][]=1&tx_myext_pi1[crit][]=2…`
and I want to have it multiple times in my RealUrl-ified URL
like `…/crit/title-of-crit-1/crit/title-of-crit-2…`
it's not working.
I only get `…/crit/title-of-crit-1…` and `…/crit/title-of-crit-2…` is missing

`…&tx_myext_pi1[crit][]=1…`
translates to `…/crit/title-of-crit-1/…` and
`…&tx_myext_pi1[crit][]=2…`
translates to `…/crit/title-of-crit-2/…`
so that part is working. But not multiple values.

Is this impossible to do with RealUrl? 
Should I make a userFunc? How?

My RealUrl Conf

```
// …
'postVarSets' => array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'crit' => array(
            array(
               'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_pi1[crit][]',
               'lookUpTable' => array(
               'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_crit',
               'id_field' => 'uid',
               'alias_field' => 'title',
               'languageGetVar' => 'L',
               'languageExceptionUids' => '',
               'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
               'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',            
               'autoUpdate' => 1,            
           ),
       ),
    ),
),
// …
```

Comment: I guess the two get params shouldn't be named identically

Comment: But those are array parameters (suffixed with `[]`). Those are intended to have those names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this impossible to do with RealUrl?

Yes, is impossible to achieve this using RealUrl.
The problem is that you are using array in the query string.

Comment: Would this be possible with cooluri or a different extension I don't know about?

Answer (score -1):

You can merge your values in one string

Like this:

```
/crit/title-of-crit-1,title-of-crit-1
```

Or

```
/crit/title-of-crit-1+title-of-crit-1
```

And split it when you need. by `,` Or `+` or another special character.

For example Drupal uses this rule for multiple values in views moudle.